# Passing variables with space to the command line as admin

Tags: windows, command-line, administrator, parameters

**strong text**script.bat placed on the sendTo folder(file setted running as admin from properties -> advanced -> run as admin)

```
@echo off

cd %~dp1

echo %~dp1

echo "%~1"

pause
```

if i pass a parameters to this file with right click-->sendto--> script.bat for example a file superuser acc.txt the script, works, but if i **run the script as admin**, a cmd windows showup for a second and dont work.

How can i run this script as admin? after this snippet of code, there is a command that require admin privilege.

edit #1 i think the problem is related to the **filename or pathname with space** inside like "c:\path to space\" or "file with space.txt" a**nd running the script as administrator.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a shortcut to your batch file in the `shell:sendto` folder and change its properties as follows:

- right click -> ˙Properties˙ -> `Shortcut` tab;
- **Target** -> `cmd /C "D:\bat\SU\931003.bat"`;
- `Advanced` button -> Run as administrator.

Note the first `echo "%CD%"` in next code snippet shows the initial working directory of your script (`"C:\Windows\system32"` if launched by `SendTo` feature):

```
==>type D:\bat\SU\931003.bat
@echo off
echo initial working directory "%CD%"
pushd "%~dp1"
echo current working directory "%CD%"
echo paramer #1 supplied "%~1"
echo all paramers %*
net session
pause
```

[image: batch shortcut in the SendTo folder (to be run as administrator)]

**Sample output**

```
initial working directory "C:\Windows\system32"
current working directory "D:\bat\1 & 2"
paramer #1 supplied "D:\bat\1 & 2\931003 test.txt"
all paramers "D:\bat\1 & 2\931003 test.txt" "D:\bat\1 & 2\batchfile.bat"
There are no entries in the list.

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Above output shows:

- works with slightly unusual path and file name containing not only spaces but even `&` ampersand character...
- works as administrator as otherwise the `net session` command returns `System error 5 has occurred` and `Access is denied` error messages.

Comment: hi, i have tryed your code. If i have a filename o pathname like "long path" with space inside, with administrator checked option dont work. the batch script is in d:\batch\run.bat, my OS is in c:

Comment: **Important**: your shortcut **target** in the `shell:SendTo` folder should be `cmd /C d:\batch\run.bat` (note that windows will translate it to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C d:\batch\run.bat` automatically after clicking `Apply`)

Comment: thanks a lot, seem work right now. i had find an issue. If the pathname of the directory with the .bat script look like "batch script inside", the script dont work. It's not a real problem, just use a simply name like "batch".

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [runas](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command as follows:

```
runas /user:username program
```

You can also use something like [elevate](http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/), a Command-Line UAC Elevation Utility, specifically for the command that requires admin privileges:

```
elevate [(-c | -k) [-n] [-u]] [-w] command

Options:
  -c  Launches a terminating command processor; equivalent to "cmd /c command".
  -k  Launches a persistent command processor; equivalent to "cmd /k command".
  -n  When using -c or -k, do not pushd the current directory before execution.
  -u  When using -c or -k, use Unicode; equivalent to "cmd /u".
  -w  Waits for termination; equivalent to "start /wait command".
```